# Flutter build wasm failing with dart:html for firebase_core_web

Tags: flutter, firebase, webassembly, dart-js-interop

Trying to compile flutter application using the experimental wasm. dart:html throws error on

.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core_web-2.5.0/lib/firebase_core_web.dart:9:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:html' is not available on this platform.

this happens when flutter build web --wasm is executed.

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/web/wasm#requires-preview-js-interop-to-access-browser-and-js-apis